# virsh console to KVM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virsh

When logged in through virsh console on to KVM. hostname is not shown properly in bash prompt. We are using 63 character hostname.

[image: bash_prompt]

KVM Guest OS:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
Host OS:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

I don't see above issue when logged in using ssh or virt-manager

hostname i'm using is Nikiabcdefdhijklmnopqrst898hd-uvwxyz-jkkdjkjdsdadjkjkkjdkjsdj90

Comment: "is shown properly" - hmm, you might want to proofread that one. What information would you like to get in an answer? It's not immediately clear to me what kind of help/information you are seeking here.

Comment: Its not** shown properly.  Updated question. I'm expecting hostname name should be showing completely in bash prompt.

Comment: If you want the authors of libvirt to fix the display, no answer we could provide here will do that, such a bugreport belongs in their bugtracker.

Comment: I'm not sure whether its configuration issue or bug. That's why posted here. I have logged redhat ticket also.

Comment: It's launching some kind of telnet ("Escape character is ^]" is a telnet message) and wrapping because the print exceeded the length of the line. On the configuration front you could get a larger window or a shorter hostname. Or both.

Comment: If so it should happen for all VMs. Why it is not wrapping for RHEL 8 based VM

Comment: Something to do with the shell prompt? Compare the values of `$PS1` and `$PS2` between the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding below line in `/etc/bashrc` resolved the issue.

```
resize > /dev/null 2>&1
```

'xterm' rpm provides resize binary.